# Same image is equivalent to Same matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $W$ is an arbitrary vector space and $T_1,T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$

I want to prove:
$\text{Im}\space T_1=\text{Im}\space T_2 \Leftrightarrow \exists S \in \mathcal{L}(V), T_1=T_2 S$

Which $S$ is invertable

Honestly I have no idea for starting prove....

Comment: Are either $V$ or $W$ assumed to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: The result is wrong in general. For example if $T_2 = \operatorname{Id}$, $T_1=S=0$. I imagine that you need also $S$ to be invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

**I suppose that $S$ is invertible.** Otherwise, the result doesn't hold. For example if $T_2 = \operatorname{Id}$, $T_1=S=0$.

The right to left direction of the equivalence is trivial.

Concerning the left to right. Take a basis $\{w_1, \dots , w_m\}$ of $\operatorname{Im}(T_1) = \operatorname{Im}(T_2)$. Prove that you can find a linearly independent family $\{v_1^1, \dots, v_m^1\}$ of vectors of $V_1$ such that $T_1(v_i^1) = w_i$ for $1\le i \le m$. Same thing for $T_2$.

Then try to define $S$ by mapping $v_i^1$ to $v_i^2$ for $1\le i \le m$.

*Note: similar proof can be done if $W$ is suppose to have an infinite dimension.*

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to prove right to left direction, actually I cant find a proper basis for proving right to left direction

Comment: As I commented to your question, the equivalence doesn't hold if you don't have a further hypothesis on $S$, like $S$ invertible.

Comment: Yes, S is invertable

Comment: @GenevaVaughn Please update your question with this important information. Then it is easy to prove that if $T_1=T_2S$ you have $\operatorname{Im}(T_1) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(T_2)$. For the converse inclusion, use that $S$ is invertible.

Comment: How to prove Im(T1)⊆Im(T2)?

Comment: Can you write what $y \in \operatorname{Im}(T_1)$ means? And what $T_1=T_2S$ implies?