# Linear Algebra and equal Images

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have $2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with equal images, does this mean that $A$ and $B$ are equal?

If not could you show me a counter example?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't. Consider any two distinct invertible matrices.

Comment: Are you talking about linear maps? If so, then what you are thinking about is functions that are injective. Injective functions have the property that you are describing. For example the identity map is injective(bijective), which is the map that outputs the same matrix. The thing is not every function is injective.

Comment: More precisely, the images are equal if and only if $B=AS$ with an invertible $S$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112263/same-image-is-equivalent-to-same-matrix). And this $S$ need not be the identity.

Answer (score 1):

No. One easy counterexample is to consider $A=I_{n}$ and $B=-I_{n}$. Notice they both have $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as their image.